# Can I get back BNB sent to contract address

Tags: smartcontracts, binance-smart-chain, bsc

I mistakeanly sent BNB to the BSC contract address `0xf4De1f6169C5a1189c0664f838BB44F293cf8cf3`. The token owners say they cannot recover the funds. Can someone please take a look at the contract and see if the BNB can be recovered? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the contract doesn't have to withdraw function, you cannot get back your BNB from the contract anyway.
I just took a look at the contract functions.
There is no withdrawal function in the contract.
Instead, there is a BEP20 token withdrawal function.

```
function recoverBEP20(address token address, uint256 token amount) public onlyowner {
        // do not allow recovering self token
        require(tokenAddress != address(this), "Self withdraw");
        IERC20(tokenAddress).transfer(owner(), tokenAmount);
    }
```

As you can see from the code, only the owner can call this function.
If you can kindly ask the owner, you may find a way to get back the BNB or equivalent their tokens.

Thank you.